# Modify input in laravel middleware

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-middleware

Some service makes HTTP request to my site and passes some input. This input has a little bit wrong structure for me, so I'm trying to modify it.

I made a middleware and attached this middleware to my route. The handle method looks like this:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $input = $request->all();

    // Input modification

    $request->replace($input);
    \Log::info($request->all()); // Shows modified request

    return $next($request);
}
```

However in my controller I got old input. Also I'm a little bit confused since I also use FormRequest, and as I realize these two requests are different entities. Then how can I modify the input in the middleware?

Comment: Is this Laravel 5 or 5.1?

Comment: can you post this `$request->replace()` method so we can see what it does?

Comment: It's Laravel 5.1 `replace()` method is built in Laravel, it's not my own method

Comment: I copied/pasted this code, set my own modifications, and it worked for me.

Answer (score 10):

I don't know what's the exact problem in your case but I'll show you what I did to make it work and it might solve your problem:

**app/Http/Middleware/TestMiddleware.php**

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class TestMiddleware
{

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param  \Closure $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $input = $request->all();

        if (isset($input['mod'])) {
            list($input['int'], $input['text']) = explode('-', $input['mod']);
            unset($input['mod']);
            // Input modification
            $request->replace($input);

            \Log::info($request->all()); // Shows modified request
        }

        return $next($request);
    }

}
```

**app/Http/Kernel.php**

```
protected $middleware = [
    'Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode',
    'Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies',
    'Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse',
    'Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession',
    'Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession',
    'App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken',
    Middleware\TestMiddleware::class, // this line added
];
```

**app/Http/routes.php**

```
 Route::get('/test', ['uses' => 'TestController@index']);
```

**app/Http/Requests/SampleRequest.php**

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Requests;

class SampleRequest extends Request
{        
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'int'              =>
                [
                    'required',
                    'integer'
                ],
            'text' => [
                'max: 5',
            ]
        ];
    }
}
```

**app/Http/Controllers/TestController.php**

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;


class TestController extends \Illuminate\Routing\Controller
{

    public function index(Requests\SampleRequest $request)
    {
       dd($request->all());

    }
}
```

In console I've run `composer dump-autoload`.

Now when I run the following url:

```
http://testproject.app/test?mod=23-tav
```

I'm getting in controller from `dd`:

```
array:2 [▼
  "text" => "tav"
  "int" => "23"
]
```

as expected and when I run for example `http://testproject.app/test?mod=abc-tav` I'm being redirected to mainpage in my case because data doesn't pass validation from `SampleRequest` (`int` is not integer)

Comment: Very strange. It works when I make requests using browser or postman, but in my case I was trying to do that from ngrok (basically I was testing webhook). In case of ngrok it don't work

Comment: According to this (https://github.com/laravel/internals/issues/48), there's a chance that FormRequest ignores middleware under certain circumstances.

Comment: If you only want to change one value, you can use $request->offsetSet(string $offset, mixed $value);

https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Http/Request.html#method_offsetSet